# $\Sigma_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^k} \leq \frac{1}{10^m}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that $\Sigma_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^k} \leq \frac{1}{10^m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Sigma_{k=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{1}{10^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{10^{m+2}}+\frac{1}{10^{m+3}}+.... =\frac{1}{10^m}(\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10^2}+\frac{1}{10^3}+...)\leq \frac{1}{10^m}\cdot1=\frac{1}{10^m}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Sum a geometric series.

**Alternative hint**.  Write both LHS and RHS as decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write $\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^k}= \frac{1}{10^{m+1}} \sum_{ k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{10^k}$ and evaluate the latter geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{10^k} = \dfrac{1}{10^{m+1}}\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{10^\ell} = \dfrac{1}{10^{m+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-1/10} = \dfrac{1}{10^{m+1}}\cdot \frac{10}{9} = \frac{1}{9 \cdot 10^m} < \dfrac{1}{10^m}$$